# net: business entity?

Tags: .net, business-objects, architecture

hi all
I would like to know that what considerations we need to do when designing business entities as a software architect?

Any reference or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Its a very broad question but some high level topics that i think you must look at include:-

Concurrency - how your objects will handle it

Caching of Business objects and how it will be done.

Persistence / Retrival of business objects 
    - If you use will use an ORM - Decision as to what ORM best fits
    your needs

Business rules validation and how it will work

Parent-child relationship management

N-level undo

Databinding Support

Transactions Support

Serialization of the business objects

Utilities like cloning (deep copy) of objects

In addition, there will be various patterns that you need to consider based on what suits your requirements best

1. What kind of responsibility pattern will they have. Eg: Expert Business objects
2. Will the objects incorporate patterns like lazy loading their data or not.

I think it would be good to explore some [ORM like NHibernate](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/NHibernateforNET) or business object framework like [Rockford Lhotka's CSLA](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/Info.aspx) as a starting point.

This should give you a pretty fair starting point and even help you decide if these frameworks meet your specific needs or you need something else.

Comment: @In Sane - A question for you: wouldn't aspects like concurrency be more of an issue for the solution as opposed to the business objects specifically?

Comment: @Adrian K - I think in some cases, the concurrency aspect could be limited to the business objects itself. However, it does depend a lot on the overall design + responsibilities of the business object.

Comment: @Adrian K - In my experience, if you are following a pattern like Expert Pattern - wherein the Business Object themselves own everything related to itself, then the responsibility of knowing that it is stale and then propogating that forward / taking action (maybe reloading itself and then filling in the updated data as long as there is no conflict + saving it) also could belong as part of the business object itself. It is from this aspect that I consider that  concurrency detection, and more importantly, how to respond to it, could also be part of the business object design

Comment: @In Sane - Thanks, very helpful.  My only other question then is: how would you structure common tasks / functionality that the Business Objects might use to do these things - I assume you'd farm truly generic stuff out to shared helper classes?

Comment: @Adrian K - Yes. The Business objects will usually use other classes which provide specific functionality a very basic example is emailing which may be handled via an email manager class. This would result in a bunch of "technical object classes" (if i can call it that) which each perform specific technical tasks supporting the "core business classes"